# Turning TIFF numpy array into a .jpeg

Tags: python, sentinel-2, numpy

I am trying to convert a numpy array - containing the Red, Green, and Blue band obtained from the .TIFF file of the satellite image - into a simple .jpeg.
The issue at hand is that the colours on the .jpeg are not like they should.

This is my code:

```
downloading_image = image * factor
im = Image.fromarray(downloading_image)
im.save("cloud_test_1.jpeg")
```

where image is a numpy array of shape (500,500,3) and factor is a float of 3.5/255

Here are the images of what I get and what I should be getting:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check out `downloading_image.dtype`, `downloading_image.shape`, `downloading_image.min()`, and `downloading_image.max()`.  JPEGs can contain three 8-bit channels (values 0-255) so you'll have to rescale your values appropriately and select 3 bands if necessary

Comment: With what factor should I rescale my arrays? I

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Comment: `255 / downloading_image.max()` or 255 / the datatype's maximum

Answer (score 1):

Change the last part of your script as follows to take advantage of [built in PIL functionality](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageEnhance.html) for brightening your image rather than converting the values in the array directly. I'm not sure exactly what your problem was before, but my best guess is that it was some sort of rendering issue. In any case, this should help you move forward.

```
## this is your original plot function
## factor 1/255 to scale between 0-1
## factor 3.5 to increase brightness
plot_image(image, factor=3.5 / 255, clip_range=(0, 1))
plt.show()


# read np array into PIL
im = Image.fromarray(image, mode="RGB")

# initialize image brightness enhancer
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(im)

#set factor
factor = 3.5  

# brightens the image by specified factor
im_output = enhancer.enhance(factor)

#plot original image
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()

#plot brightened image
plt.imshow(im_output)
plt.show()

#write out both images
im.save("output_image.jpeg")
im_output.save('brightened-image.jpeg')
```

[image]

Comment: I tried but it still does not work. I get the exact same result as from before ...

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: I don't know how to share the data on this platform, so hence I put everything in this Google Colab file: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LcM6LtCilnwLo1emZV3O2LjBgTlvZcN3?usp=sharing

Comment: You'll need to make the files public or accept my request for access

Comment: Invite sent via email!

Comment: Ok I think it should be working now. Let me know what you find when you are able to test it.